# HtmlAgilityPack in C# - Find Div without an ID

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have the current code that pulls out the version number what works fine because it has a defined div id:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
                        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
                        HtmlNode rateNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='version']");
                        string VersionNumber = rateNode.InnerText;
```

I am also trying to get a second version number form the HTML source, but this does not have a div ID. I tried using:

```
HtmlNode h2Node = doc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes["display: none"];
```

This also didn't work, so how can I find this version number, code snippet from below:

```
<div style="display: none">16.2.6011.18020|Jun-16-16 02:00:44</div>
```

HTML Source:

```
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="logonDisabledWindowTemplate">
        <div>
            <div style="padding-top: 15px;padding-left: 10px;">
                Login denied as the user is inactivated.
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="k-button blueButtonSimple" id="btnLogonDisabledOk">OK</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    <html>

    <div id="version" class="versionLogin"> Version:  16.2.6011</div>
    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="logonDisabledWindowTemplate">
    <div>
        <div style="padding-top: 15px;padding-left: 10px;">
            Login denied as the user is inactivated.
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="k-button blueButtonSimple" id="btnLogonDisabledOk">OK</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Localization.setLocalizedString("loginAuthError", "The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.");
        Localization.setLocalizedString("InvalidCharacters", "Leading spaces, *, ; ,  &gt; , &lt; , = and &quot; characters cannot be used in text values.");
        Localization.setLocalizedString("Profile_RequiredField", "Required field");
        Localization.setLocalizedStrings({
            changePwdOldPwdDidnotMatch: "Old password did not match",
            PasswordSameAsOld: "New password cannot be same as old password.",
            changePwdUnknownUser: "Unknown user",
            changePwdFailed: "Change password failed",
            MSG_12000: "Password should contain at least {0} characters. ",
            MSG_12001: "Password should contain uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers and symbols. ",
            MSG_12002: "Password should not be one of the last {0} passwords used. ",
            MSG_12003: "Unable to validate password. ",
            MSG_12004: "The password entered must be at least 6 characters and not longer than 32 characters. ",
            MSG_12005: "You have been automatically logged out for security reasons as the same user has logged on to another session. ",
            MSG_12006: "Password should contain letters, numbers and symbols. ",
            PasswordMismatch: "The passwords do not match. Please try again.",
            UserAccountLockedMsgPart1: "Your account has been locked for security reasons, as there have been at least {0} invalid attempts to log in to your account. ",
            UserAccountLockedMsgPart2: "Lock out is in force for {0} minutes. If you do not want to wait, {1}.",
            DoNotWantToWaitInstructionForNormalUser: "you can reset your password by clicking the &quot;I forgot my password&quot; link",
            DoNotWantToWaitInstructionForSysadmin: "please contact your regional admin to reset password"
        });
    </script>

    <div style="display: none">16.2.6011.18020|Jun-16-16 02:00:44</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by attribute name as well .

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);
var data = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
               .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("style",   "").Equals("display: none")).FirstOrDefault();
string version = String.Empty;
if (data!= null)
{
  version = data.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: @Scott E ,You have to include System.Linq; namespace for using linq extension methods like where  , FirstOrDefault

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Also can it be possible to say only search for that attribute after a specific div id e.g. <div class="k-button blueButtonSimple" id="btnLogonDisabledOk">OK</div>?